# How to provide source to img tag in loop in php

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have using a bootstrap modal in a table and in that modal I want to display a picture and its source is in an array which I am iterating and getting from it. But picture won't display...

This is my code

```
<table class='table table-hover table-responsive' width='21' id='tableHayatcomputers'>
<caption>Hayat Computers</caption>
<?php foreach($hayatcomputers as $hc){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $hc['name'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $hc['price'] ?></td>
<td><div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    Details
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="<?php preg_replace('/\s+/', '%20',$hc['image'])?>" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Am I missing any reference? And why images aren't iterating but names and prices are

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
array (size=4)
  'name' => string ' Nvidia Geforce STRIX-GTX970-DC2OC-4GD5 GTX 970' (length=47)
  'price' => string '
                                    Rs. 43,800                                                              Ex Tax: Rs. 43,800
                                ' (length=64)
  'link' => string 'http://www.hayatcomputers.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=1551&search=GTX+970' (length=92)
  'image' => string 'http://www.hayatcomputers.com/image/cache/data/Nvidia Geforce/11-200x236.jpg' (length=76)
  1 => 
array (size=4)
  'name' => string 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970' (length=22)
  'price' => string '
                                    Rs. 43,000                                                          Ex Tax: Rs. 43,000
                                ' (length=64)
  'link' => string 'http://www.hayatcomputers.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=794&search=GTX+970' (length=91)
  'image' => string 'http://www.hayatcomputers.com/image/cache/data/Graphics Cards/NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970  Rev 1.1-200x236.jpg' (length=105)
```

Comment: echo  the result `<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '%20',$hc['image'])?>` OR `<?= preg_replace('/\s+/', '%20',$hc['image'])?>`

Comment: OMG!!! OMG!!! OMGGGG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ALL THOSE SKILLS TURNED TO DUST!!! this happens when you code straight for 8 hours!!!

Comment: Enough programming for today! Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The `preg_replace` needs to be echoed. So do

```
<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '%20',$hc['image']);?>
```

Additionally `\s` is a white space, `+` is one or more of the previous character, so this regex is replacing multiple whitespaces with a single URL encoded space. That probably won't work as expected. I'd just use the built in [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) or [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

```
<?php echo rawurlencode($hc['image']);?>
```

or

```
<?php echo urlencode($hc['image']);?>
```

The `urlencode` uses `+` for the spaces, the `rawurlencode` will use the `%20`.

Alternatively swap each space with one url encoded space.

```
<?php echo preg_replace('/\s/', '%20',$hc['image']);?>
```

Comment: Wait a minute, why images sources aren't iterating? I mean every row should have different image right?

Comment: Dunno, what's `$hayatcomputers` look like?

Comment: Array ( [0] => name=>abc, image=>adad, price=>123, [1] => name=>aasdsad, image=>bvbv, price=>45454 )

this is what it looks like

Comment: So you have the same record twice. Look at how you build the array.

Comment: Since names and prices are iterating why is it just stuck on one picture? And yeah values are different in real this one was just example.

Comment: `values are different in real`...? Provide the real example. Why show the duplicated values and ask why they are duplicating?

Comment: Not reproducible, https://eval.in/622638. Approaching http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. In the future when/if you initialize a chat you should use it.

Comment: @ArAdAliSoomro Success?